# pam_sss(crond:session): Request to sssd failed. Public socket has wrong ownership or permissions

Tags: centos, sssd

we have Active Directory authentication with SSSD on a CENTOS 7.5

Starting from today users are unable to log in. When they try, they get:

`/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID xxxxxxxxxx`

I looked into /var/log/secure:

`pam_sss(crond:session): Request to sssd failed. Public socket has wrong ownership or permissions.`

Here's sssd.conf:

```
domains = xxxxxxxxx
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/xxxxxxxx]
ad_domain = xxxxxxxx
krb5_realm = XXXXXXXXXX
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
#use_fully_qualified_names = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
#fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
```

On another machine, with exactly the same configuration, everything works.

No changes at all, lately.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what are the ownership and permissions?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHampton. Of what precisely?

Comment: The error message says that pam is trying to connect to sssd via its public socket. Try something like `systemctl cat sssd-pam.socket` to find out where that is on your system.

Comment: Why have you posted that listing? What relevance does it have to anything?

Comment: These are my findings:

    [root@xxxxxxx ~]# systemctl cat sssd-pam.socket
    # /usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd-pam.socket
    [root@xxxxxxx ~]# ll /usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd-pam.socket
    -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 391 Sep 26  2018 /usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd-pam.socket

Comment: You are supposed to _read_ the file, not do directory listings of the file.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to format the code with triple backticks but it doesn't work...

```
[root@gmdeoim19 ~]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd-pam.socket
[Unit]
Description=SSSD PAM Service responder socket
Documentation=man:sssd.conf(5)
After=sssd.service
BindsTo=sssd.service
BindsTo=sssd-pam-priv.socket
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Socket]
ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_check_socket_activated_responders -r pam
ListenStream=/var/lib/sss/pipes/pam
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=root

[Install]
WantedBy=sssd.service
```

Comment: You aren't supposed to paste it in a comment either. Again you are supposed to _read_ it to find the socket path. It's right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.

The problem was, as stated by the error, a permission problem for the file:

```
srw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 0 Jun  1 14:30 pam
```

Fixed it by setting permissions to 0666:

```
chmod 0666 /var/log/secure
```